# DOM parser in Arabic

Tags: android, parsing, dom

I have a problem in DOM parsing Arabic letters, I got weird characters. I've tried changing  to different encoding but I couldn't.

the full code is on this link: http://test11.host56.com/parser.java

```
public Document getDomElement(String xml) {
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   try {
       Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(
       xml.getBytes("UTF-8")));
       InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);

       DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

       //InputSource is = new InputSource();
       is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
       doc = db.parse(is);

       return doc;
   }
}
```

my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<music>
<song>
    <id>1</id>    
    <title>اهلا وسهلا</title>
    <artist>بكم</artist>
    <duration>4:47</duration>
    <thumb_url>http://wtever.png</thumb_url>
</song>
</music>
```

Comment: Have you tried Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"))); with "UTF-16" instead of UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the xml as `String`, so unless that string already contains the odd characters (that is, it has been read in with the wrong encoding), you can avoid encoding madness here by using a StringReader instead; e.g. instead of:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(
   xml.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

use:

```
Reader reader = new StringReader(xml);
```

**Edit**: now that I see more of the code, it seems the encoding issue already happend before the XML is parsed, because that part contains:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

The javadoc for the [`EntityUtils.toString`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29) says:

> The content is converted using the character set from the entity (if any), failing that, "ISO-8859-1" is used.

It seems the server does not send the proper encoding information with the entity, and then the HttpUtils uses a default, which is not UTF-8.

Fix: use the variant that takes an explicit default encoding:

```
xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "utf-8");
```

Here I assume the server sends UTF-8. If the server uses a different encoding, that one should be set instead of UTF-8. (However as the XML also declares `encoding="UTF-8"` I thought this is the case.) If the encoding the server uses is not known, then you can only resort to wild guessing and are out of luck, sorry.

Comment: I tried to save the file in different encoding, it works only with ANSI, otherwise my program crashes.

Comment: I did not mean to save the file in a different encoding, but look the place where it is read in by the program and see if it is read in as utf-8. Also, did you try my suggestion of using the `StringReader` ?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the place where you read in the file? Also can you add the output of `System.out.println(xml)`? I think if you have saved the file in utf-8 and the program is reading it in in utf-8 should "just work" and feeling very puzzled.

Comment: I just added the link of the file

Comment: The weird characters have changed to "question marks symbols"... :(, does that indicate any hope, maybe?

Comment: I think I will use Databases instead of this. Im going to close this by choosing ur answer as the best one :). Thanks man & appreciate it

Comment: Thanks for voting even though it did not really solve your problem, very appreciated. I guess the next step hunting down would be to figure out in which character set the server delivers the XML - but as the server seemingly did not tell, that would end up as guesswork. Then, if your data fits in a table in a DB, better use that anyway, and not necessarily XML.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML contains Unicode characters such as Arabic or Persian letters, `StringReader` would make an exception. In these cases, pass the `InputStream` straightly to the `Document` object.