# How to pars this xml file (in dom parser) in android

Tags: android, xml

This is my return XML from my web service (asp.net) (design by myself)
        I am new in android programing  i need 
       date 
       time 
       rahbar1
       rahbar2    data please help me**

i dont know what to do

```
     <DataSet>
     <xs:schema id="NewDataSet">
     <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true"  msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">    
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="Table">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="date" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="time" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="rahbar1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="rahbar2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0/>   
    <xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
     </xs:schema>
    <diffgr:diffgram>

    <NewDataSet>
    <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
    <date>1392/10/1</date>
    <time>05:40</time>
    <rahbar1>پورقاسمي,مهدي</rahbar1>
    <rahbar2>خرسندي كلور,احمد</rahbar2>
    </Table>
    <Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
    <date>1392/10/1</date>
    <time>05:40</time>
    <rahbar1>پورقاسمي,مهدي</rahbar1>
    <rahbar2>خرسندي كلور,احمد</rahbar2>**
    </Table>
    <Table diffgr:id="Table3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
    <date>1392/10/1</date>
    <time>21:30</time>
    <rahbar1>خرسندي كلور,احمد</rahbar1>
    <rahbar2>پورقاسمي,مهدي</rahbar2>
    </Table>
    <Table diffgr:id="Table4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
    <date>1392/10/1</date>
    <time>21:30</time>
    <rahbar1>خرسندي كلور,احمد</rahbar1>
    <rahbar2>پورقاسمي,مهدي</rahbar2>
    </Table>
    </NewDataSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

What encoding this file has?

Try encoding like this in your structure:

at the beginning of your document/data.

[Refer this "DOM parser in Arabic"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791206/dom-parser-in-arabic)

Comment: thanks but the code that i mentioned is the code return from web service when i test it on explorer i made the web service by asp.net i don t know where is the encoding file i referred to the link but could not underestand